# Get PID of process using port in macos Sierra

Tags: c, macos-sierra, pid, ports

I am writing an ident server for IRC on macos Sierra, and I am having trouble with finding the owner of the port. In linux, this seems to be done with /proc/net/tcp if I remember correctly. I know it is theoretically possible, because `sudo lsof -i tcp:6697` lists the exact information I want (username and local port). I have tried going through the lsof source code on opensource.apple.com, but I was unable to locate where and how lsof does this. Google also yielded me no results beyond "Here is how to do it with lsof" or "Here is how to do it on linux". I also couldn't see anything relevant in sysctl(3). If anyone has a solution to this, or some insight, it would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: have you tried using strace with sudo lsof -i tcp:6697?

Comment: If you can find me an strace that will work with Mac I would be glad to use it. Otherwise, `sudo dtruss lsof ...` doesn't show anything relevant due to SIP